# Singly-linked list insertion synchronization

Tags: c, synchronization, sorting, singly-linked-list

Suppose I have a sorted, singly-linked list of *N* integers containing no duplicates, and *k* threads (where *k* << *N*), each trying to insert some integer (larger than the head node) into the list.

Is it possible to synchronize insertions into such a list such that:

- A thread may only block access to its (immediately) previous node 
      (No locking the "whole list")
- At most O(k) mutexes and condition variables may be used
- No preemption/interrupts may occur

?

Comment: Homework? Interview question? What have you done to attempt to answer this yourself? And what does this have to do with C?

Comment: I'm working on a personal project and the problem I'm currently facing (which is more complex) reduces to what I ask above. I'm trying to implement the solution using pthreads in C, that's why I added the c-tag. Should I provide some more implementation detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if insertion into the collection is anything but a very infrequent task, then linked lists aren't a great solution for this - because finding the insertion point is an `O(N)` operation, even for a sorted list, and hence going to end up scaling badly.

If you still need to do it, it's possible to perform insertion (unlike deletion) into a sorted list as lockless operation, with some care:

1. Find insertion point, `cur`
2. Create new node (assign prev/next linkage to `cur`/`cur->next`)
3. Atomic op: `compare_and_swap(cur->next, new, new->next);`
   If fail: `if (new->value == next->value) return; // someone beat us to it`
   Else: `cur = cur->next` and repeat the dance (list is sorted, someone inserted before us)

I.e. the outcome of the attempt to link a new node in is either that we succeed, or that someone beat us to inserting the same node (in which case we're ok - it's already there), or someone inserted into a gap (i.e. existing was `N`, `N+3`, we tried `N+1`, someone else succeeded `N+2`) in which case we retry till we succeed or find 'our' node done by someone else.

It's far more difficult to synchronize deletion; lookup RCU (Read-Copy-Update) for that.

Comment: Wouldn't locating the insertion point as such inherently lead to a readers-writers problem? I.e., we cannot be searching for or finding the insertion point curr if the list ahead is being modified.

Comment: You're testing for "earlier than", and that point will not be changed by insertion (notice: I'm not saying _modification_ because that'd include deletion). Within the "atomic dance" you might have to _advance_ the insertion point if another inserter raced you, but you'll never need to step back.

Comment: @FrankH. I didn't get why there are three arguments for compareAndSwap. In Java it will be (oldObject, newObject), what is the third argument here?